# how to rename key value of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
$abc = array(
              array(0=>354,1=>2),
              array(0=>358,1=>1),
              array(0=>344,1=>1),
              array(0=>374,1=>5),
              array(0=>364,1=>1)
              );
```

and i want to rename key value 0 to product_id and 1 to qty. so finally i want array like that

```
$abc = array(
              array('product_id'=>354,'qty'=>2),
              array('product_id'=>358,'qty'=>1),
              array('product_id'=>344,'qty'=>1),
              array('product_id'=>374,'qty'=>5),
              array('product_id'=>364,'qty'=>1)
              );
```

how can i do it?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transfer them into another one, and then use the necessary keys and loop them with `array_combine()`:

```
$abc = array(
              array(0=>354,1=>2),
              array(0=>358,1=>1),
              array(0=>344,1=>1),
              array(0=>374,1=>5),
              array(0=>364,1=>1)
              );

$new_keys = array('product_id', 'qty');
$new_abc = array();
foreach($abc as $val) {
    $new_abc[] = array_combine($new_keys, $val);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_abc);
```

Should result into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 354
        [qty] => 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 358
        [qty] => 1
    )
    .. and so on
```

Alternatively, you could also use `array_map()` for this purpose:

```
$new_keys = array('product_id', 'qty');
$new_abc = array_map(function($piece) use ($new_keys){
    return array_combine($new_keys, $piece);
}, $abc);
```

Comment: thanx! that's the solution what i was looking.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach($abc as &$element) {
    $element['product_id']=$element[0];
    unset($element[0]);
    $element['qty']=$element[1];
    unset($element[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map()` in php and try like this

```
$abc = array(
              array(0=>354,1=>2),
              array(0=>358,1=>1),
              array(0=>344,1=>1),
              array(0=>374,1=>5),
              array(0=>364,1=>1)
              );

$newArr = array_map(function($abc) {
    return array(
        'product_id' => $abc['0'],
        'qty' => $abc['1']
    );
}, $abc);
print_r($newArr);
```

[Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for more

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
unset($arr[$oldkey]);
```